# Code metric for single class

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, code-analysis

Is it possible to calculate code metric for single class in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate? I try to refactor class and I want to know what is beginning values and the code analysis for whole project take much time.

Comment: You need it to run on the whole project so it can calculates the depth of inheritance and class coupling. I doubt you can opt out of those two metrics to run it on a single class.

Comment: And by the way if you really want to use the Maintainability Index, use the [IEEE thresholds](http://www.ecs.csun.edu/~rlingard/comp589/ColemanPaper.pdf) of 85 and 65 for medium and low. VS placed medium at a ridiculous 20. I've used it a couple times on legacy code, and some mind-blowingly bad and horrible spaghetti code scored about 60, so IEEE scores makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the tool NDepend for that. The tool integrates with VS2013 Ultimate. It comes with many [code metrics](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics), that you can query through [code queries LINQ (live)](http://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL), and [visualize through treemaping](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/treemap-visualization-of-code-metrics). A 14 day full-featured trial can be [downloaded](http://www.ndepend.com/download).

Also a code metrics recap can be shown for each classes, with diff since an arbitrary baseline in the past you can choose.

[image: NDepend Code Metrics]

*Disclaimer: I work for NDepend*